# Как получить хеш данных в sha512 с солью

Tags: php

Как получить хеш данных в sha512 с солью? У меня есть соль и данные, но захешировать не получается, мне не интересен hash_hmac (с ним есть проблемка).

Comment: sha512 не является алгоритмом шифрования. Вы перепутали с хешированием?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = "data";
$salt = "salt";
echo hash("sha512", $data.$salt);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! На етом форуме есть очень классные люди.